# Is there a Joomla Plugin for Aptana IDE?

Tags: eclipse, joomla, aptana

I use Aptana for 2 or 3 months now and i'm very happy with it.
But since i need to work with Joomla! and to write some modules, compenents, etc...
I'd have like to know if there is a joomla plugin for Aptana ?

I would just like to have autocompletion, autosuggest, links to methods and class of the Joomla API

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution to enable Joomla code assist in Aptana Studio is in this video [www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HCqomfey34](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HCqomfey34). This is for Aptana Studio 3.

After creating your project, go to Project > Properties > PHP Buildpath > External Directories > Add... and choose the Joomla framework folder (your_joomla_folder/libraries/joomla).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware, there isn't any.

But I think for what your looking for this will depend on actually how you set up your development environment. To start, you could use the aptana PHP plugin, then create a new 'Joomla' Project,  pointing to your entire Joomla folder.

I use aptana but solely for javaScript. none-the-less if autocompletion and autosuggestion are what you are looking for with php, u will love phpEdit or phpDesigner, once you create a new project, and point to the source folder, you are ready to start working. Unlike aptana and eclipse, (though you could) you won't need to add specific code libraries to the project!!

Answer (score 0):

Codelobster PHP Edition is FREE but the Joomla plug-in is NOT you can download the IDE with a 30day trial of the plug-in...